How do I use a server from another installation?
I have 2 Windows installations (let's call them A and B) on my hard drive. I have a MySQL server on A. I want to install MySQL on B and have it use, update, and do other stuff to the database I made on A. So basically, I want both of them to work on the same database or schema.
While configuring MySQL for B using the configurator, I tried setting its data directory to that of A but apparently the directory has to be empty so I just went with the default path.
Going back to the server on A, I moved its Data folder to the root of the partition so that it's accessible. I changed the path of datadir on my.ini to the new location.
I already installed MySQL on B but I'm just a hobbyist and I'm doing this for a small personal project so I don't know how to proceed with this.

install in a vm and run that under both windows?

You can't have more than one mysql instance working on the same data files.
